Using gstreamer on Windows with Python
Is there any way to use gstreamer using python on Windows?
I have tried this :
import os 
import gi 
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0') 

from gi.repository import Gst, GObject, Gtk

They are working good on Linux but on Windows, I'm getting error for gi.

Have you checked this? https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-windows.html?gi-language=c

The gi package refers to GObject. It is not available by default on Windows. I haven't tried this because I don't use Windows, but there is PyGObject which provide bindings for Windows: https://pygobject.gnome.org/getting_started.html#windows-logo-windows

This question is similar to: gstreamer python bindings for windows. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I'm getting error for gi. what error?
